# Unique combinations from list with "distance limit"

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

Given the list `a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`, I would use `itertools.combinations` to get all unique combos like `['ab', 'ac', ...]`, as per the classic [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

**How can I limit the unique combinations to items that are not farther away than `n` spots?**

*Example*

If I want list items no more than `n=2` spots away, I would accept `'ab'` and `'ac'` as combinations but not `'ae'`, because the distance between `'a'` and `'e'` is greater than `n=2`

*Edit - code*

Below the plain python code solution, which I'd avoid due to the double-for loop, that is not ideal for large lists

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
n_items = len(a)
n_max_look_forward = 2

unique_combos = []
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    for j in range(i+1, min(i+n_max_look_forward+1, n_items)):
        unique_combos.append( item+a[j] )

print(unique_combos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity-wise, your solution is close to the best possible.
You could refactor it to be a generator to generate the values only when you need them so that you don't have to hold all of them in memory at the same time:

```
def combis(source, max_distance=2):
    for i, item in enumerate(source):
        for j in range(i+1, min(i+max_distance+1, len(source))):
            yield item+source[j]
```

You can then iterate over the generator:

```
>>> for combi in combis(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']):
...     print(combi)
...
ab
ac
bc
bd
cd
ce
de
```

If you need all of them in memory as a list, you can still use the generator to initialise it:

```
>>> list(combis(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']))
['ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'ce', 'de']
```

Comment: I think I can prob do with 1 loop only (where you keep i and j in a while loop and increment one or the other)